# How to get image path in Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop

Want to change images in my slider from img to background, before in my template images get by the code:

```
<img src="{$link->getMediaLink("`$smarty.const._MODULE_DIR_`homeslider/images/`$slide.image|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'`")}"{if isset($slide.size) && $slide.size} {$slide.size}{else} width="100%" height="100%"{/if} alt="{$slide.legend|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" />
```

Now i want to make background for every slide like this:

```
{$image_url=$link->getMediaLink("`$smarty.const._MODULE_DIR_`homeslider/images/`$slide.image|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'`")}

<li class="homeslider-container" style="background-image:url("  {$image_url} ")">
```

But i am getting string without slashes, this is from my browser:

```
<li class="homeslider-container" style="background-image:url(" http:="" anirionline.com="" modules="" homeslider="" images="" ")"="">
```

How can i do that? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

try `{$image_url|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}`
There are other [escape](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.escape) modifiers like `quotes` that you also might want to try